# How to add AllowEncodedSlashes On to httpd.conf Ubuntu

Tags: apache2

How to add `AllowEncodedSlashes On` in httpd.conf?

I'm using Apache/2.4.18...

I can't find httpd.conf in `/etc/apache2`

I read [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) saying that `httpd.conf` does not exist.

Then, how I can add that `AllowEncodedSlashes On`?

Comment: Add it to `/etc/apache/apache.conf`, or to a specific file in `/etc/apache/conf-enabled`.

Comment: @muru that sounds like an actual answer.

Comment: @ThomasWard it does, but I don't know what the allowed contexts for this option are, and I'm too lazy too look them up and write an answer.

Comment: hahaha.... help me